# Restrict Indexing of documents/binary/multimedia component on SOLR

Tags: si4t, binary, solr

We are using SOLR Indexing for Search module implementation. Trying to restrict the indexing into SOLR by controlling using a NoIndex field in the metadata of the Page as well as the binary component is given in the below link.

http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/inside-si4t-search-integrations-controlling-what-gets-indexed

In spite of this, the documents are getting indexed.
Would like to know if there is any way to restrict this from the SOLR side.

We were able to get hold of the code but would like to know how to pass the NoIndex metadata field (present in binary component) into SOLR. Would like to add a condition to check this and control it from getting indexed.
https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/tree/develop/storage-extensions/src/main/java/com/tridion/storage/si4t

[image: JPASearchBinaryContentDAO.java where the binary content is recognized to be indexed]

Can anyone suggest how this can be done Or if any other alternate solution for this?
NOTE: this is for any multimedia/binary component added on the page.

Answer (score 1):

SI4T based SOLR search integration framework already has the option to restrict indexing of binaries by file extension.

You can configure **DocExtensions="pdf,docx,doc,xls,xlsx,pptx,ppt"** in **cd_storage.xml**

Sample:

```
 <Indexer Class="org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer" DefaultCoreUrl="http://localhost:8080/solr/staging" Mode="http" DocExtensions="pdf,docx,doc,xls,xlsx,pptx,ppt">
```

Refer to the full [SI4T Solr Configuration Configuration](https://github.com/SI4T/Solr/wiki/SI4T-Solr-Configuration-101)

**Update:**
SI4T extension based on deployer storage extension point, I'm not sure it's possible to get the binary metadata in that transaction. one option you could
customize by **extends JPABinaryContentDAO implements BinaryContentDAO** with the binary filename you can able to filter to index.

Comment: Hey thanks.. but we do not want to restrict based on the DocExtensions. As we would like to only not index specific documents (secure ones) and not all.
 
For example, we may have 10 PDFs and out of that we need to index 8 of them, 2 of them based on "NoIndex" should not be indexed.
Can you please suggest another way to do it?

Comment: updated my answer